# Can an owner ban a person from a property when a contract is in place?

Tags: contract-law, property, mail

Recently I angered the owner of a UPS Store that I have a contract and service agreement with. He canceled my service agreement. He also declared I was banned from the property for life.

The problem I'm facing is I have packages en route. According to our contract after termination or end of the service agreement, I can choose to have the packages stored at a daily rate for periodic pick-up or forwarded at my expense.

In keeping with the contract and not wanting an irate person to have my new address, I told him, I would like any packages that arrive to be stored at my expense.

Can he really ban a patron with a contract that obligates him to serve the patron?

In case it matters:

- there has and will be no violence
- there have and will be no threats (by me)
- this occurred in California

Thanks!

---

**Update**
I'm including the contract, because of the inquiries. I don't wan't it to distract from the actual question in the title, regardless of whether my situation is deemed different.
[Contract](http://www.theupsstoredc.net/mailboxForm.html)

Comment: What does the contract say about attending the store?

Comment: - "Customer will not use the Center premises or any Center services for any unlawful, illegitimate or fraudulent purpose"
- "Possession of the Mailbox key shall be considered valid evidence that the possessor is duly authorized to remove any contents from the Mailbox"
- one more mention of electing to have packages stored and pick them up

Answer (score 4):

He can probably cancel your contract for cause and ban you. If he does so, you can send someone else to get the packages, forward them to someplace other than your home, or retrieve them with a "civil assist" coordinated with law enforcement.

Comment: According to corporate the contract remains in force. Only the service agreement portion can be canceled by the store owner. 

My question still stands can an owner ban a patron from their property if a contract is in place that requires the patron use the property?

Comment: @N-ate: from what you have said, the contract does *not* require that you attend in person. Accordingly, he can ban you and the contract can be fulfilled in other ways.